# Powershell Conditional filter without regex

Tags: powershell, filter

Im trying to filter ADComputer by  Name.

Our naming  convention  is  a  follows `<CuntryCode>-<Location>-<DeviceType And Number>` we have diferent  locations  in both  USA and  MX,  we also have serval  type of  devices

Example:
`<Device Type>`
`Servers  = S`
`Desktops = D`
`Laptops = L`
`Tablet = T`
`Routers = R`
`Switches = U`

example of  actual naming:

**MX-BCN-D002  or  US-TAM-L001**

Im creating  a  Script  that  will  look  at a remote PC  file  system, and check  if  user has  a local  .PST file.  I  only  want   devices  that  are   Type:   Desktops  and Laptops,  but  cant seem  to  create a condition to  filter all other  devce  type

Partial  Script:

```
$Enabled_PC_list =@()
$Enabled_Online_PC_List =@()
# $Enabled_Offline_PC_list =@()
$data = @()

$PCs = Get-ADComputer -filter "Enabled -eq '$true'" -SearchBase "DC=some,DC=domain" -properties name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name

$Enabled_PC_list += $PCs

foreach($device in $Enabled_PC_list){

    Write-Output ">>> testing  Device: $device <<<"
    if ($device -like "*-*-D*" -or  $device -like "*-*-L*" ) {
        if(Test-Connection -TargetName $device -Count 1 -Quiet){
            $Enabled_Online_PC_List += $device
        }

    }else{
        Write-Output "Device  $device not valid "
    }


    }
}
```

So  with this  line  `if ($device -like "*-*-D*" -or  $device.name -like "*-*-L*" )` i  was hoping to filter out  all devices  that matched   what  im looking  for and proceed  to do  a   Test-Connection  on those  devices .

Do  i need  to use  regex  on this ?
How  can i  use  regex in powershell?
Is there  a  better  way ?

Comment: Your Laptops, Desktops and Servers not in separate OU's?

Comment: yes  and   no,  I  have  diferent  OU's    by  location ..  
example:    `domain.com\USA\US-TAM\Computers\ ... and  a  OU  for  device  types`
                  `domain.com\USA\MX-BCN\Computers| ... and  a  OU  for  device  types`

Comment: ```Get-WmiObject -Class win32_systemenclosure``` can also be used to determine device type. Since your naming convention has a method to identify desktop or laptop you can use the last part of string like ```$deviceName = "MX-BCN-D002"
$nameSplit = $deviceName -split "-"
$deviceType = $nameSplit[2]
if ( $deviceType.StartsWith('D')) {

Write-Host "$deviceName is Desktop"
} elseif ($deviceType.StartsWith('L')) {

    Write-Host "$deviceName is Laptop"
} ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading though your replies, it  got  me thinking  if    LDAP  can do the  filtering,   could    powershsell   do it  to?   so  i  tried  this  and  it  works

the  where  clause  did  the  trick  `Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*-*-D*" -or  $_.Name -like "*-*-L*" -or $_.Name -like "*-*-T*"}`

```
$Enabled_Online_PC_List =[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$Enabled_Offline_PC_list =[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
# $data = @()

$searchBase = "OU=USA,DC=some,DC=domain"


$Enabled_PC_list = Get-ADComputer -filter "Enabled -eq '$true'" -SearchBase $searchBase -properties name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*-*-D*" -or  $_.Name -like "*-*-L*" -or $_.Name -like "*-*-T*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name

foreach($device in $Enabled_PC_list){
# Write-Output "testing  now  $device"
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $device -Count 1 -Quiet){
        Write-Output " Now Adding  $device to  Enabled_Online_PC-List"
        $Enabled_Online_PC_List.Add($device)
    }else{
        Write-Output " Now Adding  $device to  Enabled_Offline_PC_list"
        $Enabled_Offline_PC_list.Add($device)
    }
}
Write-Output $Enabled_Online_PC_List
```

so  script  is  working  time  is  cut  off dramatically,  now  i  ask  again is there a  better  way?  for  some reason LDAP  does not  want to stick in my head

Answer (score 2):

You can do this better by letting Active Directory do the filtering for you, instead of filtering from your side. You can generate an [LDAP Filter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) via string manipulation adding an LDAP Clause for each device type:

```
$filter = '(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(|'
'S', 'D', 'L', 'T', 'R', 'U' | ForEach-Object {
    $filter += '(name=*-*-{0}*)' -f $_
}
$filter += '))'

$onlinePCs = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter $filter -SearchBase "DC=some,DC=domain" | Where-Object {
    Test-Connection -TargetName $_.DNSHostName -Count 1 -Quiet
}
```

The generated LDAP Filter would look like this (with some formatting):

```
(&
  (!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)
  (|
    (name=*-*-S*)
    (name=*-*-D*)
    (name=*-*-L*)
    (name=*-*-T*)
    (name=*-*-R*)
    (name=*-*-U*)
  )
)
```

And can be read as, **all enabled objects** (computers in this case because we're using `Get-ADComputer`) which Name attribute is like `*-*-S*` or `*-*-D*` or `*-*-L*` and so on.

Comment: o wow   looks   scarry !    let  me  deep dive  into  LDAp  .. Thanks

Comment: Additional  question !  does  LDAP  filter  would  work  faster that traditiona  PS Commandlets   ?     The  thing  is   the  script  is   working    but  takes  a very  long time  to process  each  machine ...  and   its  processing  unwanted  machines   that makes  it  take  longer  thats  why  i want  to  filter  out  all  unwatned  device  types

Comment: @victorR letting AD do the filtering will always be faster than filtering on client side since less objects are brought to you. you can add an additional layer of filtering for something more refined using regex if needed though

Comment: Thank  you  sir  !    I'll def. will take a  look  at  LDAP  filters

Comment: @victorR np, as for `Test-Connection` that will always be slow, you can give [this function](https://github.com/santysq/PS-NetScanners/blob/main/Test-ICMPConnectionAsync.ps1) a try if you want to test ICMP async in powershell. that will speed up the whole process.